# datagridview date column sorting problem during header click in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

> Blockquote

In vb.net one of the column in the data grid view is shown as issue_date with dd/mm/yyyy format but when i click on the header of that column it only can sort by the column by numeric value how can i sort by according to the date?

that mean when that is 01/09/2010,02/09/2010,01/10/2010 it is now sort by

01/09/2010 01/10/2010 02/09/2010

> Blockquote

how can i sort according to date:

01/09/2010 02/09/2010 01/10/2010

Comment: please help me...

Comment: How EXACTLY did you populate the grid in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s presumed by your explanation your column type is a `String`. It’s not a correct `ColumnType` to display a `Date` but ***every one has its own reasons***. However in this case the code below helps you:
Note that, in this class I control even the type is a `Date` (in case you decide to change the `ColumnType`, but in this case column sorting is natural by its self) and not only a `String`.

Hope is that what you need

```
Private Class ColumnDateComparer
    Implements System.Collections.IComparer

    Private Direction As Integer = 1
    Private Index As Integer = 0

    Public Sub New(ByVal ColumnIndex As Integer, ByVal sortOrder As SortOrder)
        Index = ColumnIndex
        If sortOrder = SortOrder.Descending Then
            Direction = -1
        ElseIf sortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending Then
            Direction = 1
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer _
        Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare

        Dim DgvR1 As DataGridViewRow = CType(x, DataGridViewRow)
        Dim DgvR2 As DataGridViewRow = CType(y, DataGridViewRow)

        Dim dt1 As Date
        Dim dt2 As Date

        Dim rObj1 As Object = DgvR1.Cells(Index).Value
        Dim rObj2 As Object = DgvR2.Cells(Index).Value

        If TypeOf (rObj1) Is Date Then dt1 = CDate(rObj1)
        If TypeOf (rObj2) Is Date Then dt2 = CDate(rObj2)

        If TypeOf (rObj1) Is String Then
            Date.TryParse(DirectCast(rObj1, String), dt1)
        End If

        If TypeOf (rObj2) Is String Then
            Date.TryParse(DirectCast(rObj2, String), dt2)
        End If

        Return dt1.CompareTo(dt2) * Direction

    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

Change `Column1.Index` with `YourColumnOfDate.Index`

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    DataGridView1.Sort(New ColumnDateComparer(Column1.Index, SortOrder.Descending))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your underlying data is probably not a date. This sorts fine (make a new project, double click the form and paste this on top of the form load event):

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("name")
    dt.Columns.Add("Birthdate", GetType(DateTime))
    dt.Rows.Add("John", New DateTime(2000, 1, 1))
    dt.Rows.Add("Mary", New DateTime(1960, 1, 1))
    dt.Rows.Add("Luke", New DateTime(1980, 1, 1))

    Dim dgv As New DataGridView
    Controls.Add(dgv)
    dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    dgv.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Store your data in a DataTable. Make the column to be of type DateTime, Store DateTimes. Bind the table to the grid. Happy days

Even happier days if you add an item of type DataSet to your project, then open it, right click the surface, add a DataTable, right click it, add columns, set names and types appropriately. DataTables [made this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgoE6.gif) are a lot nicer to work with